# Align right bootstrap grid which center aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap grid system.
I have 3 grids which aligned center:

```
<div id="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-centered">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
                <p>
                   Logo
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
                <h3>
                   Some text
                <h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-centered">
                <ul class="list">
                        <li>
                            <img src="img_url"/>

                            <a class="phones" href="+1-380-555-5555">+13805555555</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img_url"/>

                            <a class="phones" href="+1-380-555-5555">+13805555555</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="img_url"/>

                            <a class="phones" href="+1-380-555-5555">+13805555555</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS looks like:

```
.row-centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.list {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f1f0e9;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Trirong', serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align-last: right;
}
```

In third grid I have  which I want to be aligned right.
text-align: right helps, but when I switch to mobile mode bootstrap makes grids in a column and third grid become right aligned(two others centered).
So I need that third grid will come right aligned but inside parent grid which has center align. Is it possible?

Comment: It's better to provide a chunk of real code instead of heap of unclosed tags.

Comment: It looks like you need to add `col-sm` and `col-xs` rules too.

Comment: @Banzay thanks, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

I have separated columns on two `<ul class = "list">` objects and add

```
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
```

properties to *list* class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `text-align-last: right;` property because it's not affect to the `a` tag inside `li`. Use `.list:last-child a` will select the last `li` tag and affect to its `a` tag.

```
.row-centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.list {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f1f0e9;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Trirong', serif;
    list-style-type: none;
    /*text-align-last: right;*/
}

.list li:last-child a{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Nothing change.
It does change color of the <a>  for example, but seems to inherit center align from parent.

Comment: Nothing change


.list li:nth-child(n)  {
    text-align: right;
}


move n element to right similar to


.list {
    text-align-last: right;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try add a `pull-right` class to those you want right